# Fastest way to calculate the similarity kernel between matrices of strings?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, vectorization

Say I have a list of 5 matrices called `data`. Each matrix has an arbitrary number of rows but exactly 3 columns that contain 3 strings. I want to train a Gaussian Process model and let's say `data` is my training set. I want to calculate the similarity kernel based on the string matching of every pair of matrices. Let's say the 5 matrices look like below:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([# Matrix 0
                 [['b', 'a', 'c'], 
                  ['a', 'a', 'b'], 
                  ['d', 'c', 'c'], 
                  ['a', 'b', 'd']],
             # Matrix 1
             [['d', 'a', 'c'], 
              ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
              ['a', 'd', 'd']],
         # Matrix 2
         [['a', 'b', 'b'], 
          ['d', 'a', 'd'], 
          ['d', 'b', 'a'], 
          ['c', 'b', 'd']],
     # Matrix 3
     [['b', 'b', 'c'], 
      ['a', 'b', 'b'], 
      ['a', 'c', 'a'], 
      ['c', 'b', 'a'], 
      ['b', 'd', 'd']],
 # Matrix 4
 [['a', 'b', 'c'], 
  ['c', 'a', 'b'], 
  ['d', 'd', 'c'], 
  ['a', 'a', 'a']]
], dtype=object)
```

I want to calculate the similarity between every two matrices. Let's use the first two matrices as an example. They have 4 and 3 rows, respectively. I want to check the string matching of all `4 x 3` pairs. In each pair, we say the difference between each pair of strings (only compares 0-0, 1-1, 2-2) is `0` if they are the same, otherwise `1`. This will returns a binary vector `diff` and then be fed into a squared exponential (or RBF) kernel to get the similarity score between **this pair of rows**. Then I calculate the similarity scores between all pairs of rows (0-0, 0-1, 0-2, 1-0, ..., 3-0, 3-1, 3-2) and sum them together, and this value is the final similarity between the first and second matrices. I then do this for all pairs of matrices, and I can get a final similarity kernel `R` and its normalized version `K`. Below is my implementation:

```
from itertools import product
import math

def kernel(data, sigma=1.):
    # Initialize the similarity kernel
    R = np.zeros(shape=(len(data), len(data)))

    # Get every pair of matrices (including themselves)
    for iprod in list(product(enumerate(data), enumerate(data))):
        idxs, prod = zip(*[(i, c) for i, c in iprod])
        ks = []

        # Get every pair of rows between the two matrices
        for pair in list(product(*prod)):
            diff = (np.asarray(pair[0]) != np.asarray(pair[1])).astype(int)

            # Squared exponential kernel
            k = math.exp(-np.dot(diff, diff) / (2*sigma**2))
            ks.append(k)

        # Calculate sum and insert it into R[i,j] and R[j,i]
        ktot = np.sum(ks)
        R[idxs[0],idxs[1]] = ktot
        R[idxs[1],idxs[0]] = ktot

    # Normalize the similarity matrix R
    d = np.diag(R)**-0.5
    K = np.diag(d).dot(R).dot(np.diag(d))

    return K

K = kernel(data)
print(K)
```

Output:

```
[[1.         0.81009275 0.71374617 0.7365101  0.81061262]
 [0.81009275 1.         0.68228781 0.70349301 0.82009247]
 [0.71374617 0.68228781 1.         0.78137859 0.68976163]
 [0.7365101  0.70349301 0.78137859 1.         0.7365101 ]
 [0.81061262 0.82009247 0.68976163 0.7365101  1.        ]]

%timeit 2.86 ms ± 64.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

However, my code becomes very slow when there are much more training data or there are much more rows in each matrix. My speculation is that this is because I am using `itertools.product` too much and there is no matrix operation. I feel like there should be a fully vectorized `numpy` way to do this. I am thinking of `np.cov` and `np.kron` but don't know how it could work for strings. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get about one order of magnitude faster for the case of the list provided in your example if you replace the inner loop vectorized calls. I do not know how to vectorize the outer loop, as `data` consists of differently shaped arrays... Anyways, in the following snippet we use broadcasting to operate between arrays in a pairwise fashion, as well as `einsum` for extra coolness ;). The improvement is not as much as that obtained from @Jérôme Richard, but it only uses NumPy!

```
def kernel_oneLoop(data, sigma = 1.):
    # Convert matrices to arrays first
    data = np.array([np.asarray(d, dtype = object) for d in data])
    # Initialize the similarity kernel
    R = np.zeros(shape=(data.size, data.size))
    # Iterate through upper triangular matrix indices
    idx0, idx1 = np.triu_indices_from(R)
    for i in range(idx0.size):
        diff = (data[idx0[i]] != data[idx1[i]][:,None]).astype(int)
        # Squared exponential kernel (no need to square as they're 0's and 1's)
        k = np.exp(-diff.sum(axis=-1) / 2*sigma**2)
        # Calculate sum and insert it into R[i,j] and R[j,i]
        R[idx0[i],idx1[i]] = k.sum()
    # Normalize the similarity matrix R
    d = np.diag(R)**-0.5
    K = np.einsum("i,ij,j->ij", d, R, d)
    # Symmetrize
    K = K + K.T - np.diag(np.diag(K))
    
    return K
```

**Edit**: as well pointed out by Jérôme, as the output is a symmetrical array, we could just loop over the upper triangular indices of the array. I updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Numba's JIT** to speed up a bit the hottest loop of the computation. However, Numba does not support strings very well yet. Thus the strategy is to **convert the string into factors** first (unique integer identifying strings). The benefit of this method is also to significantly speed up the row comparisons. Moreover, several additional optimizations can be applied:

- replacement of the slow `product` calls by **simple nested loops**
- computation of the summations on-the-fly
- manual computation of the norm (since the result of the `!=` is a 0|1 boolean value)
- take advantage of the **symmetry** to divide by 2 the number of operations

Here is the resulting implementation:

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
from itertools import product


# Actual computational kernel
# Work on a list of 2D arrays containings 32-bit integers contiguously stored in memory
@nb.njit('float64[:,::1](ListType(int32[:,::1]), float64)')
def computePairs(data, sigma):
    # Initialize the similarity kernel
    matCount = len(data)
    R = np.ones(shape=(matCount, matCount))
    normFactor = -1.0 / (2*sigma**2)

    # Get every pair of matrices (including themselves)
    for i in range(matCount):
        for j in range(i, matCount): # Note the matrix is symetric
            ktot = 0.0

            # Get every pair of rows between the two matrices
            for a in data[i]:
                for b in data[j]:
                    sqNorm = 0

                    for k in range(len(a)):
                        sqNorm += a[k] != b[k]

                    # Squared exponential kernel
                    ktot += np.exp(sqNorm * normFactor)

            R[i,j] = ktot
            R[j,i] = ktot

    return R

# Transform the list of list of list of strings into a list of 2D factor arrays
def convertData(data):
    labelToId = {}
    labelCount = 0
    result = []
    
    for labelMat in data:
        height = len(labelMat)
        factorMat = np.empty((height, 3), dtype=np.int32)

        for rowId in range(height):
            row = labelMat[rowId]
            for cellId in range(3):
                cell = row[cellId]

                if cell in labelToId:
                    labelId = labelToId[cell]
                else:
                    labelId = labelCount
                    labelToId[cell] = labelCount
                    labelCount += 1

                factorMat[rowId, cellId] = labelId

        result.append(factorMat)

    return nb.typed.List(result)

def kernel_fast(data, sigma=1.):
    data = convertData(data)

    R = computePairs(data, sigma)

    # Normalize the similarity matrix R
    d = np.diag(R)**-0.5
    K = np.diag(d).dot(R).dot(np.diag(d))

    return K
```

This is about **45 times faster** on my machine on the small provided input example. About 70% of **the time is spend in data conversion**. This means that the computation can be roughtly 3 times even faster if the input would directly fit to the provided algorithm.

If you plan to work on bigger matrices or more of them, please note that you can **parallelize** the above algorithm to make it even faster (it does not worth it for small inputs).